# OCaml work with JPEG

Tags: ocaml, jpeg

With CamlImages, how can I find the color of a point in the coordinate XY

```
let () =
  let name  = "test.jpg" in
  let image = Jpeg.load name [] in
```

image has type Images.t

but fun Rgb24.get requred type Rgb24.t

```
  (* get color from coords XY *)
  let x = 1 and y = 1 in
  let rgb = Rgb24.get image x y in
  print_int rgb.r;
```

I tried all the functions from the library, but not found solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jpeg.load` returns `Images.t` whose definition is:

```
type t =
   | Index8 of Index8.t
   | Rgb24 of Rgb24.t
   | Index16 of Index16.t
   | Rgba32 of Rgba32.t
   | Cmyk32 of Cmyk32.t;;
```

All you need is to pattern match the result of `Jpeg.load` and get `Rgb24.t`:

```
let rgb24 = match Jpeg.load name [] with
  | Rgb24 x -> x
  | _ -> failwith "image must be rgb24"
```